# p:commandLink window.onload

Tags: javascript, primefaces

In a page I display charts (chart.js) and I have to use window.onload JS for loading.
The page is called by p: commandLink but window.onload does not work.
I did not find a solution on the web.
Can you help me please ?
Thank you.
My code:

```
<p:commandLink value="Espace standard" 
                           style="position: absolute; top: 455px; left: 700px"
                           action="pageGraphiqueEspaceStandard.xhtml" 
                           actionListener="#{utilitaireManagerBean.initialiserPageCourante('graphiqueEspaceStandard')}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function ()
                {
                    drawChart('espaceStandardGraphique1', 'idCanvasGraphique1');
                    drawChart('espaceStandardGraphique2', 'idCanvasGraphique2')
                };
</script
```

Comment: I found a solution with window.onload by adding ajax = false to call the page,
but a blank page appears briefly before displaying the page correctly!
How to disappear this blank page?

Comment: Make use of [document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) instead of [window.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) and give it a try.

Comment: I tried document.onload instead of window.onload but it doesn't work.